# Asp.net core 2.2 slow upon first request

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, c#-3.0, typescript2.0

The first request takes time to hit the server API method because it pre-building the services in a start-up task can anyone suggest me to reduce the initial latency of my first request after published in IIS

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. 
            // Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
               services.AddTransient<IContactService, ContactService>();
               services.AddTransient<IPersonService, PersonService>();
               services.AddTransient<IDashboardService, DashboardService>();
               services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
               services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

                // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
                services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
                {
                    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
                });
            }
```

Need to inject more than 100 services its taking time to prebuilding.

Comment: Solution is now valid for Linux base deployment. I have asp.net core 3.1 web api project. any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

This might be an issue with your IIS configuration as the **Application Pool** is recycled from inactivity.

If you set the ApplicationPool's **Start Mode** under *Advanced Settings* it should be ready to be used whenever you call it, unless you happen to call it just as the recycling is happening.

This can be found by:

1. Open IIS
2. Locate *Application Pools* under your server root
3. Right-click the specific *Application Pool* you want to change
4. Choose *Advanced Settings*
5. Change **Start Mode** to *AlwaysRunning*

[image: Advanced Settings Start Mode]

For the latter issue of it recycling whenever it wants to (every 29 hours), you can schedule the recycle to happen at a set time to be unobtrusive. On the same *Advanced Settings* screen:

1. Location the **Recycling** heading
2. `Change Regular Time Interval (minutes)` to 0
3. Expand `Specific Times` and click the `...` where it says TimeSpan[] Array.
4. In the new dialog choose a static time outside of operating hours for the refresh.

[image]

Comment: The question mentioned "after publishing". Changing these IIS settings will not benefit initial request performance after deploying.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, "Always Running" will initiate the startup immediately when the deploy is complete. That should ensure the readiness when that first request is made not waiting for the first call.

Answer (score 2):

for me setting  Idle Timeout to a higher value solved the problem

[image]